# Arguments for Judaism from the existence of irrational antisemitism

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah, anti-semitism, proof-of-torah

The visibility made possible by social media has exposed, in sharper relief and magnitude, what has always been there - the hugely disproportional (in terms of relative population percentages) and at the core irrational hatred of Jews. From regular people on the street, to news organizations, to government officials, it is present in all layers of society. I don't think there's any other ethnic/national/religious minority on Earth that this can be compared to, making the Jewish people unique in this regard. There is also no rational explanation that would account for the scope, ferocity, and how innate and deep seated this hatred seems to be.

Personally I find this to be an even stronger argument/proof for Judaism than the Kuzari argument and others. This phenomenon of "Eisav soneh l'Yaakov" just doesn't really "make sense", and can only be explained in a suprarational and supernatural way, and it's openly observable by anyone (who's willing to look around without bias).

Have there been emunah arguments of this sort made historically in Rabbinic literature?

Comment: Presumably very few of those people think they are being irrational

Comment: Right, it's irrational when viewed from an outside (objective., rational) perspective. For example, no matter how much Israel goes out of its way to be more humanitarian, restrained and patient than any other country would have even thought of doing, the hatred is not diminished by that (in fact, it seems to flair up).

Comment: again very few of them think they aren't the objective rational ones. Very few people at all don't think that about themselves.

Comment: loosely related https://aish.com/48900712/

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course people don't consider themselves irrational. I don't think OP is suggesting anti-semites would find an argument predicated on the irrationality of anti-semitism compelling. The question is whether ordinary people would find it notable.

Comment: @shmosel precisely

Comment: @DoubleAA True. What's that got to do with the question?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Not such a useful proof if the person you are trying to prove it to doesn't accept the premise

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand the question as being related not to those who act irrationally but to a neutral third-party observing from the side, and wondering why the Jews get different treatment than other populations. That neutral third-party does observe irrational behavior since he is not influenced by his own beliefs on . I personally agree with the views expressed by the OP.

Comment: @mbloch Why do you assume a neutral third party would notice excessive hatred?

Comment: @DoubleAA if you speak with people who have no bias, e.g., in Asia, they often report being puzzled by the treatment of Israel and Jews

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there anything in this question about proving to antisemites that they are irrational? "Does the disproportionate amount of antisemitism in the world prove Torah true in an enumah argument" i.e. aimed at Jews mainly

Comment: @RabbiKaii I don't know where you see "aimed at Jews mainly" but Jews can be antisemties too and/or be irrational.